# How to edit lost messages in msc protocl diagram

Tags: diagrams, msc

I am using the development version of the `msc` package to draw a protocol message sequence diagram. I have the following diagram.

[image]

I want the lost messages to arrive in the next level (not the same level - straight line) and I need to increase its length. This is how I want it to be:

[image]

Here is the original script.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{msc} %for the diagrams
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BEGIN DIAGRAM
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{figure}[ht!] 
\[
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
   \centering
\setmsckeyword{} 
\drawframe{no} 
\hspace{-1cm}
\begin{msc}[small values, /msc/left environment distance=2cm, /msc/level height=0.6cm, /msc/label distance=0.5ex, /msc/first level height=0.75cm]{} 

\setlength{\instwidth}{2.5\mscunit} 
\setlength{\instdist}{2\mscunit} 

\declinst{A}{}{A}%
\declinst{X}{}{X}%
\declinst{B}{}{B}%

\mess {message 1} {A}{X}
\nextlevel
\lost[side=left]{}{}{X}

\nextlevel
\mess {message 2} {A}{X}
\nextlevel
\lost[side=left]{}{}{X}


\end{msc}
} %end scalebox
 \]
 \caption{Illustration}
\end{figure}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   END DIAGRAM
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: that won't compile cleanly with my version of `msc` package.  I get: `! Package msc Error: illegal title placement specifier: small values, ...`

Answer (score 2):

Note to other users: this code is written for the development version of `msc`, available from http://satoss.uni.lu/software/mscpackage/. It will not work with the version of `msc` that is on CTAN.

---

The length of that arrow is defined by the relative coordinate `++(\msc@dist,0)` in a macro called `\msc@lost@final`. You can use `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` to patch that macro, replacing the coordinate with for example `++(2.5*\msc@dist,-10pt)`.

To make the line start on the same level, move `\nextlevel` to after `\lost[...`, as in the code example below.

As in one of your other questions, I removed the math environment (`\[ .. \]`) because it doesn't really make sense to use it, and I removed the `\resizebox` because I don't see that you need it.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{msc} %for the diagrams
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\msc@lost@final}{++(\msc@dist,0)}{++(2.5*\msc@dist,-10pt)}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BEGIN DIAGRAM
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{figure}[ht!] 
\centering
\setmsckeyword{} 
\drawframe{no} 
\begin{msc}[small values, /msc/left environment distance=2cm, /msc/level height=0.6cm, /msc/label distance=0.5ex, /msc/first level height=0.75cm]{} 

\setlength{\instwidth}{2.5\mscunit} 
\setlength{\instdist}{2\mscunit} 

\declinst{A}{}{A}%
\declinst{X}{}{X}%
\declinst{B}{}{B}%

\mess {message 1} {A}{X}
\lost[side=left]{}{}{X}
\nextlevel
\nextlevel
\mess {message 2} {A}{X}
\lost[side=left]{}{}{X}

\nextlevel

\end{msc}
\caption{Illustration}
\end{figure}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   END DIAGRAM
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```